# Unity: "Set as Layer Default State" does not show whenever I right-click on an animation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently in Lesson 3.3 of Unity's "Junior Programmer Pathway" - I've run into an issue, the ["Set as Layer Default State" does not show whenever I right-click on an animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEJLT.png). The only options are shown in the SS. Any help appreciated.
Version: 2020.3.31f1

Comment: haha...sorry, I meant "Unit 3.3", I'm currently in the "Junior Programmer Pathway". I updated my question.

Comment: Haha my bad then .. this makes more sense ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround.
Right-click Entry and select Set StateMachine Default State, this will disconnect the connection to Idle now click on Run_Static